# Why my custom dimension in my imagemosaic doesn't work in geoserver getmap request?

Tags: postgis, geoserver

I have an imagemosaic with a custom dimension. My custom dimension is appered in Edit Layer -> Dimensions menu and in capabilities document.

```
...<Dimension name="CUSTOMDIMENSION" default="9.0" units="EPSG:2100" unitSymbol="m">9.0,10.0,11.0</Dimension>...
```

But when I run a request GetMap
    http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?service=WMS&CUSTOMDIMENSION=9.0&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap...
the custom dimension it doesn't filter my data...

The indexing of imagemosaic is stored in postgis and it seems to be fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the answer is to add DIM_ prefix before your CUSTOMDIMENSION parameter... In my case http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?service=WMS&DIM_CUSTOMDIMENSION=9.0&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap...